# "Reviewing post"-screen is too big

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, design

I think the "Post-Review screen" expects a too big monitor. And should be more adaptable to screen size.

Here is an image of the review screen:

[image]

**Problems:**

1. Action buttons are hidden on the right side; I have to scroll right to see the buttons.
2. The orange text area exceeds the window, even though there is actually no need for it.
3. The orange text area is not removable. It covers about half of the screen for information, that is not permanently needed. (I would expect an "×" at the top left of the message)
4. Because of (3) The actually interesting are (green) has only half of the screen to present data.
5. The information "This is the first question asked by a new user ...." has probably its reason for existance, but I know this is a first-questioner, because I choose so when I chose which kind of questions I wanted to review.
6. Usually posts are read from top to bottom. So the (blue) buttons in the top right might rather go in the bottom right? This would also free up space in the top - more space for real content.

Comment: Deferred since the review UI is currently being reworked.

Comment: I blame the introduction of the left hand menu for the horizontal scrolling... You can turn that off, you know; just go into Edit Profile and Settings and under Navigation there's a checkmark for Hide left navigation. That will put that nav in a "hamburger" menu on the top left, allowing more horizontal real estate for important things. Doesn't address all of the issues, but might help.

Comment: The _(less)_ button hides the orange box, its toggleable. That covers 2, 3 and 4. 5 is just a reminder of what the queue is for and I think not an issue. 6 I just disagree with.

Comment: What are your monitor dimensions?

Comment: @zcoop98 Varying. I don't understand to which extend the monitor dimensions are important here...

Comment: @Dark Only relevant if excessively small or something... I was referring to the idea that your window width would be constrained by the width of your monitor.

Comment: @zcoop98 That would be resolution, not dimensions, I can see just as much on my phone as on my PC (even if the links are harder to click). I find SO review queues function fine for a resolution of 1366x768, although haven't personally tried anything smaller

Comment: @Nick Fair point! I made the mistake of assuming they consistently go hand in hand... they *sometimes* do, but not always.